# jquery limiting amount of json Data that is presented on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

This is a snippet of my code on my site which displays json data onto the html page however, theres a lot of data on the json file. how would I limit the number of movies(data) being shown to 5.

```html
  function actors(actors) {
  return `
<h5>Actors</h5>
<ul class="actors-list">
${actors.map(actor => `<li>${actor}</li>`).join("")}
</ul>
`;
}


function movieTemplate(movie) {
  return `
    <div class="animal" >
    <img class="movie-photo" src="${movie.info.image}">
    <h2 class="movie-name">${movie.title} <span class="species">(${movie.info.rating})</span></h2>
    <p><strong>Year:</strong> ${movie.year}</p>
    ${movie.info.actors ? actors(movie.info.actors) : ""}
    </div>
  `;
}

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
  <h1 class="app-title">movies (${movieData.length} results)</h1>
  ${movieData.map(movieTemplate).join("")}
  <p class="footer">These ${movieData.length} movies were added recently. Check back soon for updates.</p>
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIurA.png)

This image shows the data being shown however thousands of movies are being shown I only want 5.

Answer (score 0):

To limit the data you can use the slice function `arr.slice([begin[, end]])`

```
<ul class="actors-list">
    ${actors.slice(0,5).map(actor => `<li>${actor}</li>`).join("")}
</ul>
```